# How I can host rpm and deb packages for free

Tags: rpm, deb

I'm a contributor to this community: https://github.com/kimchi-project

We generate distro packages for users to install, and later publish them for the distros.

Is it possible to host this packages in our repository, like the ppa one, in a free server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build and host an RPM packages on https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/